# Universal forgery based on mathematical problem

Tags: signature, dsa, protocol-analysis, forgery, hardness-assumptions

It is known that DSA admits universal forgery under assumption that the Attacker can solve the equation $x\equiv R^x\pmod p.$ Are there any other protocols admitting universal forgery based on non-trivial mathematical problem?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. If you allow some highly non-trivial mathematical computation, then _any_ signature scheme / protocol can be broken. So what specifically is your question? Whether there exist other schemes which allow for UF if some "non-obviously-associated" computation can be carried out?

Comment: @SEJPM Yes, exactly. My question is about "non-obviously-associated" mathematical problems which allow to construct UF for some protocols.

Comment: Just a note: In most popular signature schemes (which usually have a security proof, *DSA being an exception) such a "hidden security assumption" would be caught by the proof not working.

Comment: @SEJPM: Apparently, reducibility of DSA and ECDSA to the corresponding discrete logarithm problem was finally proved by Manuel Fersch, Eike Kiltz and Bertram Poettering's [_On the Provable Security of (EC)DSA Signatures_](https://doi.org/10.1145/2976749.2978413), in proceedings of the 2016 ACM SIGSAC Conference on Computer and Communications Security. It flies above my head, though.

Answer (score 2):

[Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) admits universal forgery if the Attacker can solve the equation
$$z=\frac{\psi_{k-1}(x,y)\psi_{k+1}(x,y)}{\psi_{k}(x,y)^2},$$ where $k$ is unknown, $\psi_{k}(x,y)$ are [Division polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_polynomials)  and $(x,y)$ are the coordinates of a point $P$ on the elliptic curve $ E:y^{2}=x^{3}+Ax+B$. This UF is based on the formula for the coordinates of the nth multiple of $ P(x,y)$:
$$kP=\left(x-\frac{\psi_{k-1}(x,y)\psi_{k+1}(x,y)}{\psi_{k}(x,y)^2},\ldots\right).$$

The question [Elliptic curve sequences needed for universal forgery](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290741/elliptic-curve-sequences-needed-for-universal-forgery) about hardness of this UF was asked at MathOverflow separately.